# How to use a xml api

Tags: php, xml, api

I have played around with json, but I'm just starting with xml how would I load this url and then parse the gamertag?

The url is like this:

```
http://xboxapi.xxxxxxx.co.uk/profile?apikey=$key&gamertag=$gamertag
```

and it returns

```
<xbox status="success" version="0.0.9">
  <gamertag>l RaH l</gamertag>
  <motto>I Win With Randoms</motto>
  <avatar>
      <full>http://avatar.xboxlive.com/avatar/l rah l/avatar-body.png</full>
      <small>http://avatar.xboxlive.com/avatar/l rah l/avatarpic-s.png</small>
      <large>http://avatar.xboxlive.com/avatar/l rah l/avatarpic-l.png</large>
  </avatar>
  <gamerscore>12550</gamerscore>
  <biography><![CDATA[Bio]]></biography>
  <recentactivity>
      <game>
          <title>Xbox.com</title>
          <artwork>/Content/Images/Presence/xboxcom.jpg</artwork>
          <presence>Last played less than a minute ago</presence>
      </game>
      <game id="1297287259">
          <title>Halo: Reach</title>
          <artwork>http://tiles.xbox.com/consoleAssets/4D53085B/en-US/largeboxart.jpg</artwork>
          <gamerscore>
              <current>1205</current>
              <outof>1400</outof>
          </gamerscore>
      </game>
      <game id="1297287142">
          <title>Halo 3</title>
          <artwork>http://tiles.xbox.com/consoleAssets/4D5307E6/en-US/largeboxart.jpg</artwork>
          <gamerscore>
              <current>1750</current>
              <outof>1750</outof>
          </gamerscore>
      </game>
  </recentactivity>
  <freshness>new</freshness>
</xbox>
```

Comment: goooooooogle.... **AHHH its the google ghost!!!**

Comment: ^ like spooky Neal says... [take your pick](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php) (simplexml or DOM come to mind).

Comment: Use the search function please. There is plenty of examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to read up on PHP's built in XML processing features

SimpleXML would be the easiest option
http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

or you can go through DOMDocument manually

also make sure your xml has a valid xml declaration at the top

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```